# How do you evaluate code maintainability of HTML5 vs. Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, html, maintainability

Comparison of HTML5 and Silverlight as Web development platform is a popular topic, and arguments often focus on readiness of HTML5 or additional step to install Silverlight plug-in. But let's say there are no such issues: all browsers have good support for HTML5, and all browsers come with built-in Silverlight. I know it's false assumption, but it helps me focusing on something else: with such assumption made, what would you choose for rich Web client development in a .NET development team?

I believe one of the important factors then will be code writing experience: how easy is to write clean code, how easy to maintain it over long period of time? Do you have any experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

With Silverlight 4 and Ria Services I think it's getting pretty obvious that the future of the technology lies in data focused business applications (well.. and the coming windows mobile 7 - which would better use the Desktop WPF ...).

HTML5 will, IMHO be multimedia focused.

... WTFs per second.

Comment: AFAICT the advent of RIA and MVC the DFS for the WWW application space is full of multiple value propositions to be evaluated on a best ROI basis.  MTBF and TCO are not directly relevant but should also be considered.  Silverlight represents a viable platform delivery option along with Flash and HTML 5, though none really enjoy a standards validated status.  But no, really... which is easier to write and maintain?  Words or ideas?  The philosophy is clear but the answers are not yet.  WTF per second per second.

Comment: But my question was mainly about maitainability. Whether it's business or multimedia purpose is a different matter.